# Enabling Screen Sleep using RTSP stream

Tags: camera, screen, security, rtsp

I have two IP cameras supporting RTSP, and I want to display their feeds on a monitor fed by a Raspberry Pi. My problem is that I do not want the monitor to be powered on 24/7, but only when a motion event is detected.

How can I go about doing this? Is there an existing software with this functionality? I looked at https://github.com/Anonymousdog/displaycameras but I wasn't able to find any screen sleep or motion detection functionality.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, sounds like you want to blank the screens and then wake them up when an event happens: bit like a screensaver would? Might be worth investigating using something like https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion to "spoof" a keypress to wake the normal OS powersaving features?

Comment: Addendum: There's also https://linux.die.net/man/1/xscreensaver-command to stop (and start) the screensaver, rather than trying to "spoof" a keypress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many IP cameras have some kind of API that you can use for detecting motion. Hikvision cameras (Hikvision also sells to re-branders, so just because the case doesn't say Hikvision doesn't mean that it's not a Hikvision inside) for example, have an XML-based API they call ISAPI, where you can specify what should happen when the camera detects a motion event in a region of interest (ROI). Another common API is ONVIF. Google these terms, you'll find a lot of information. There is lots of really bad code out there; I found it a lot easier to just read the Hikvision documentation and write everything from scratch (sorry, can't share the code, this was for a client).

By the way, avoid Uniquiti cameras like the plague if you want to do anything more than what their GUI allows you to.